# Can I verify that a Google Tag Manager id is valid?

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager

It looks like, from inspection, that the form of a Google Tag Manager id is "GTM-XXXXXX" where the x's are [A-Z]|d, is this accurate? I need to verify whether the id's being submitted to a CMS are valid.

Answer (score 3):

I've just wrote this one for our framework:

```
/^GTM-[A-Z0-9]{1,7}$/
```

Tested with 25 GTM container IDs in our account, all passed validation. You can try this expression out [here](https://regexr.com/3s5n1).

Comment: Have you seen any ID with just 1 character though? I've only seen 6 and 7, are shorter ones older?

Comment: Yep, you're right, you could tighten up the length of the ID part. I've not seen anything from Google to say it would be invalid to have fewer than 6 characters there. This could just as easily expand beyond 7 at a later date when GTM gets popular enough.

Answer (score 1):

The format varies. I see various combinations of numbers and letters, some just letters, none just numbers, most 6 characters, and few with 4 characters. There's no clear pattern. They begin with either a letter or number, and end with a letter or number.

Comment: I haven't seen a GTM tag with other than six characters after the '-', though it makes sense that there might be more. 36^6 is a big space (assuming case-insensitive and 0-9) but might not be big enough.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping there would be some rhyme or reason to the id, but there isn't. I have clients with 4 digit/letter id as well. But most of the time it's 6.

Comment: Might be a case of security through obscurity also, where there is a format but they don't want to disclose. Ahh well....